# Why my branch pending after merged in sourcetree graph

Tags: git, graph, merge, pull-request, sourcetree

My problem is like this: I have a master branch. To release a new version, I made some version related changes and commit the changes. I used to push directly, while now I realized that it is not a good idea. So I checkout a new branch sfma_build. Then I push this local branch to remote repo, and pull request. After that, I merged the remote sfma_build into remote master. Now in sourcetree, the graph looks like this:
[image]

While I think the graph should look like this:
[image]

I mean, origin/sfma_build branch has already been merged to origin/master branch, right? So there should be line segment connecting back to form a cycle? That's what I see when other branches are merged.

Comment: Does a `git fetch` helps updating the graph?

Comment: @VonC No, it does not.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with BitBucket as the remote.

Answer (score 0):

We had this same issue until we changed our merge strategy on BitBucket. It's hard to tell from your cropped images, but in our case we changed to `squash and merge`. The merge commit is important because it has multiple parents, one to the branch you initiated the PR from and the other to the last commit in the branch you PR'ed to. You can use `git log --parents` to see the difference between a merge commit with multiple parents and what the commit in your screenshot looks like.

Based on this forum answer it looks like Bitbucket just recently added new merge strategies - https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/44341546/manual-squash-merge-detection-in-bitbucket-server-and-closing-pull-requests